# How to activate a Jbutton by clicking another Jbutton

Tags: java, swing, jbutton

There are 7 buttons in my project. 6 of them are categories and RandomSoru button is the one which randomly chooses one of the categories. I want to access the chosen category. "r" is the random generator.

```
RandomSoru.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        TriviaLinked tl = new TriviaLinked();


        tl.insertAtBack(tl.CogHmap);
        tl.insertAtBack(tl.TarihHmap);
        tl.insertAtBack(tl.SporHmap);
        tl.insertAtBack(tl.BilimHmap);
        tl.insertAtBack(tl.FilmHmap);
        tl.insertAtBack(tl.SanatHmap);

        TriviaNode current = tl.root;

        int n = r.nextInt(tl.sizeCounter());

        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            current = current.next;
        }
        if(current.hmap==tl.CogHmap)
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Your Category is Cografya");

        else if(current.hmap==tl.SporHmap)
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Your Category is Spor");
            ....
```

Here is the Spor button

```
Spor.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {


    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    ......
```

My expectation was like

```
 else if(current.hmap==tl.SporHmap)
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Your Category is Spor");
        Spor();
else if(current.hmap.....
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is to add the 6 buttons to an ArrayList.

Then in the `ActionListener` of the random button you could do something like:

1. Use the `Collections.shuffle(...)` method to randomize the buttons in the `List`.
2. Then you get the first button from the `List`.
3. Finally you invoke the `doClick()` method on the button.